If I roll 10 dice, each with a 1/3 chance of success, and I need at least 3 successes for the trial to succeed, what is the percent chance of success?
So a bit of background: I play a TTRPG (like DnD) that uses a D6 system. The system uses 6-sided dice, where a dice counts as an individual success if it rolls a 5 or a 6, so a 1/3 chance of success. I have been trying desperately to convert one of my more frequent rolls from 10 d6s (6-sided die) to one d100 (100 sided dice). This means, I must find the percent chance of my roll being an overall success.
I know each dice is its own Bernoulli Trial, and I need to use some Binomial Trial formula to get the answer, but I just can't find the right set up!
The roll is 10 (6-sided) dice, each with a 1/3 chance of individual success. In order for the whole trial to be a success, at least 3 must be individual successes.
or:
n (number of trials) = 10;
p (probability of individual success) = 1/3;
i (number of success needed) = >2
Please help! This problem has been plaguing me for so long, that I'm pretty sure my character is gonna DIE before I can even use it, haha!
Edit: also, if someone could show me how to set up the problem and explain why it works, that would be great. I'm really interested in doing more recreational probability stuff, so I'd love to also see the process.

Read about the binomial distribution in any textbook and/or on wikipedia.  Note that it may be less effort to find the probability of failure instead since this will require fewer terms.

Shoutout to the person who said to look at the Binomial Distribution formula, I had never seen it before and that really helped. I found the answer:
$P(x\geq 3) = 1 - P(x<3)$;
$P(x<3) = P(x=2) + P(x=1) + P(x=0)$;
$P(x=2) = \binom{10}{2}\times(\frac{1}{3})^2\times(\frac{2}{3})^8 = .1950922125$;
$P(x=1) = \binom{10}{1}\times(\frac{1}{3})\times(\frac{2}{3})^9 = .08670765$;
$P(x=0) = \binom{10}{0}\times(\frac{1}{3})^0\times(\frac{2}{3})^{10} = .0173415299$;
$P(x<3) = .1950922125 + .08670765 + .0173415299 = .2991413924$;
$P(x\geq 3) = 1 - .2991413924 = .7008586076$
=70.1% of overall success.
(Let me know if I made any mistakes)

You have to use the binomial distribution formula which is $P(X=x) = \binom{n}{r}p^x q^{n-x}$, where p is the probability of success in an individual trial, n is the number of trials, q is the probability of failure and r is the number of successes.
Since you need at least 3 successes, you have to calculate the probabilities of all the trials in which at least 3 dice throws are a success. An easy way of doing this is deducting trials with 0, 1 and 2 successes from 1.
Also can someone explain how can I properly visualize operations like exponention, division, combinatorics, etc on this website?

Do you mean "visualize" as in "typeset"? If so, you can look at how Red Five edited your post, by clicking on "Edit" under your answer. (Just hit cancel after you've inspected the editable answer.) Broadly, exponents can be written simply as $a^{2x}$ for $a^{2x}$, subscripts as $b_{kq}$ for $b_{kq}$; the binomial coefficient can be written either $\binom{n}{k}$ for $\binom{n}{k}$, or more awkwardly, ${}_nC_k$ for ${}_nC_k$. (The empty braces in the last example are there for improved kerning if there is something before the binomial coefficient.)

Is there an article about the rest of these combinations? Like fancy x's and radicals?

You can take a look at the MathJax tutorial page.

$1-((\frac{2}{3})^{10} + (\frac{2}{3})^9\times(\frac{1}{3})\times\binom{10}{1} + (\frac{2}{3})^8\times(\frac{1}{3})^2\times\binom{10}{2})=0.7$

I think this is a correct answer, but it could do with a brief explanation of where the terms come from. Also, the $LaTeX$ command \binom{n}{r} can really help formatting of these expressions.

No. of Dice: = 10
S: Success of one dice
F: Failure of one dice
$P(S) = \frac{1}{3}$
$P(F) = \frac{2}{3}$
$S_t$ = Success of trial
$F_t$ = Failure of trial
$P(S_t) = 1-P(F_t)$
Case 1 of failure:
If you not get S in any of 10 dices.
$P(F_{t0}) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{10}$
Case 2 of failure:
If you get S in only 1 of 10 dices.
$P(F_{t1}) = \binom{10}{1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{9}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$
$P(F_{t1}) = 10*\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{9}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$
Case 3 of failure:
If you get S in only 2 of 10 dices.
$P(F_{t2}) = \binom{10}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{8}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}$
$P(F_{t2}) = 45*\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{8}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}$
$P(F_t) = P(F_{t0})+P(F_{t1})+P(F_{t2})$
$P(F_t) = 0.299$
$P(S_t) = 0.701$
Therefore you have 70.1% chance of success.
